# OpenELEC for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3

Will there be a new version of OpenELEC for the Raspberry Pi 3? Or would the install file for the Raspberry Pi 2 work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fully supported in the latest release (6.0.3):

http://openelec.tv/news/22-releases/175-release-openelec-6-0-2-released

> full RaspberryPi 3 support including onboard WLAN and Bluetooth

Comment: Will this mean it takes full advantage of the much faster CPU speed on the Pi 3?

Comment: There's no reason why it wouldn't, but there's nothing specific listed in the release notes for that version.